# Adding members Trello

Tags: trello, account-management

Everytime I add someone in Trello they are able to create an account but they never receive the verification email. HELP! A team of just me isn't a team. I will have to give up on Trello if I can't add other members and have them finish their registration.What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

If someone hasn't gotten their confirmation email, they can cause another one to be sent by visiting

**https://trello.com/resendValidate**

The emails that Trello sends generally go out within a few seconds of being generated, so **if you aren't getting an email almost immediately, something has probably gone wrong.**  (There have been some reports of Trello confirmation emails being flagged as spam, so it's a good idea to check your spam folder)

If you still aren't getting the validation emails, and resending them isn't helping, then email **support@trello.com** from the email address that is associated with your Trello account, and they can manually send you the validation link.